# Automatic sprite creation & css mixin script for PHP?

Tags: php, css, sass

I've been doing a lot of work on build automation in PHP for a framework library.
I was about to start bashing at the keyboard when I thought... "someone's got to have done this before".

However after some digging I haven't found anything which can do exactly what I'm after and thought I'd ask around here:

I need a PHP script which can:

1. Take a preset directory full of images (jpg/png/gif mixed)
2. Sprite them all together into one file i.e. "UI.png" or something
3. Open up a bunch of css files & scan for instances of the individual files
4. replace the src `url()`
5. Adjust any existing background positioning rules

It sounds like a lot to do but I can't be the first person to be considering this can I?

I've seen a few scripts around which do either the first part or attempt to do the 2nd part but with a tonne of config comments which I'd rather avoid.

Any ideas?

Comment: May the force be with you. Always.

Comment: lol... yer... was hoping that some yoda had been here before...

Comment: It seems like quite a big ask. But I don't know much about PHP so maybe it's not, sorry I can't be of more help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a tool that could help you: https://code.google.com/p/scrinker/  . It shrinks css files and automatic generates rudimentary sprites like icons by just adding /*[[SPRITE]]*/ to your background declaration.